# Stop Prompt for Password Expiration Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, context.xml

Every time my application connects to its database (AS400), it shows a prompt "Your password will expire in X days".

This causes the application to hang while waiting on YES/NO selection.

I am working with security to get the passwords updated/extended, but I was curious if there was a way to ignore prompts like this in the context.xml file, so the application does not hang in the meantime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `;prompt=false` to the end of the connection URL as according to [JDBC properties list](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/doc-files/JDBCProperties.html) provided for `AS400JDBCDriver` this is the only property which might have an impact on your problem.